# Oracle - select all rows with highest x of specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

There are two columns in the table: `name` and `score`.

I want to select all rows which has highest 5 values of `Score`.

```
| NAME     | SCORE    |
| -------- | -------- |
| Jake     | 10       |
| Park     | 10       |
| Rone     | 9        |
| Tom      | 8        |
| Joe      | 7        |
| Clark    | 7        |
| Emily    | 6        |
```

Please note that it's **not** `top 5` rows. I want **all rows** with highest **5** SCORE values.

Is it possible in Oracle?

I googled and found 'FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY' stuff but this was not what I've been looking for.

Comment: Could you please give an example of result you are expecting in above sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use window function:

```
select * from (
  select * , dense_rank() over (order by score desc) rn
  from table
) t where rn <=5
```